# Node.js with Chaplin: structure

Tags: node.js, chaplinjs

How is the file structure like when using Chaplin with node.js?

I've downloaded the brunch-with-chaplin and that seems pretty straight-forward, but where do I place my node.js files?

I have my app.js file for node, but where do I place it and how do I launch my Chaplin app with it? I wouldn't like to mix the server side files with chaplin files..

Answer (score 1):

They should be either placed directly in the root e.g. I typically have a server.js file which resides in the root.  Then optionally you would have sub-directories such as controllers, models, routes etc. depending on how you decide to structure your solution.

Here's an example of a project I'm working on right now.

```
/app - this contains you front-end application logic i.e. chaplin
  /controllers
  /lib
  /models
  /views
  application.js
  routes.js
/controllers
/models
/routes 
server.js - node.js main, starts up express/connect etc.
```